# big mysql database optimization

Tags: mysql, php

My Joomla mysql database has about 3.4 million rows in content table. It is just static article. Very slow and often use out of resources. To speed up it, I segmented it into 6 sub-tables and added many indexes.

However, the problem still there and some times more serious. Current situation:
Memory used out, could not connect to database, table locked
500 and 404 errors reported by Google webmaster tool 16000 times per day,
Some pages load quickly but some pages load slow or not show(query long time, 10 minutes, or 30 minutes more)

My VPS is host gator level 7.

Please give me some advices on how to change the situation.

Comment: It's hard to give even small advice without seeing a DB/table structure or query. Throw one or two which, you think, most complicated.

Comment: In Joomla with SEO URLs on, you might have a bottleneck pulling an article because it selects by the title/alias instead of the PK.

Comment: @MrCode you are right! I disabled seo url and find the speed is very fast! What else do you advice?

Comment: The question was moved here because SO folk decided it was off-topic there. However in order to get a good response here and avoid having the question closed here too, you will need to make the question more specific. I suggest you follow the advice given and post more details of the queries run and the table/index structures.